# How can I use the Microsoft Edge WebView2 control in C# windows application

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, webview2

How can I use the Microsoft Edge WebView2 control in C# windows application using Visual Studio?

Comment: If you want to get started with webview2, 
I have a simple c# WPF example on GitHub that can be helpful:
https://github.com/GrooverFromHolland/WebView2_YoutubeBackingTracks/tree/master/YoutubeBackingTracks

Answer (score 6):

Now in 2020 WebView2 supports both WPF and WinForms so you can try to use it in your application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf

Basically you need to add Nuget package Microsoft.Web.WebView2 and then use WebView2 control.

Comment: Don't forget to install the correct version of Edge.  Currently (May 22, 2020) that is 84.xxxxxxx.  The how to documentation doesn't call this out nearly clear enough.  Nor is there error checking for the correct version.  (NullReferenceException if the correct version of Edge is not on  your machine)

Comment: @BradBruce What if you only have the version that comes with Windows Update? The API will be pretty useless if incompatible with Microsoft pushed versions...

Comment: Added the nuget package, but WebView2 does not appear in the toolbox? (vs 2019)

Answer (score 3):

The [Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) (powered by Microsoft Edge (Chromium) as the rendering engine) is available on the following programming environments: Win32 C/C++ (GA), .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later, .NET Core 3.1 or later and .NET 5.

**Get started with WebView2**

1. Install prerequisites on your machine:

   - [WebView2 Runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
   - [Microsoft Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
2. Create a Windows Forms Application.
3. Install WebView2 [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) in your project.
4. Drop an instance of the WebView2 from toolbox on your form.
5. Set the Source property to a valid URL like: https://example.com and run the application.

**More information**

- [Getting started with WebView2 in Windows Forms apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms)
- [Sample WinForms Application - GitHub Repository](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot currently do it without some hacks as it is missing the interfaces. It only support C++ win32 API for the time being. Please see this post for more information https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebViewFeedback/issues/46

Comment: Please note that this is NO LONGER the case.  .NET/C# now has a very good NuGet package that allows most of the functionality available in the C++ version.  The issue you highlight in your answer is now closed and many of us have now been using WebView2 easily in our .NET windows forms projects.